# How do you programatically 'relative import' a directory of jar files?

Tags: java, jar, tomcat6

I am using Drools Planner which ships with 21 Jar files in a directory `binaries`. For example the 
`drools-core-5.3.0.Final.jar` would provide `org.drools.someClasses`.

The included examples run it in command line by running an all-inclusive command:

```
mainClasspath=
for i in binaries/*.jar; do mainClasspath=${mainClasspath}:$i; done

mainClass=org.drools.planner.examples.app.DroolsPlannerExamplesApp
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -server -cp ${mainClasspath} ${mainClass} $*
```

---

I am developing the program in commandline. But the final application (which just adds a HTTP interface) runs in a JSP container, not from a commandline. Hence I need to **programmatically import** the jar files into my project.

**Question**:How do I programatically import the the jar files?

Do I rather have to specify the `binaries` path in the environment variable?

---

### Update

I did this  to tell Java that globally, extra classes may be found in the same directory, meant by the `.` and `/home/jesvin/dev/drools/binaries`. Note that `:` is the separator in Linux.

```
declare -x CLASSPATH='.:/home/jesvin/dev/drools/binaries'
```

You can do it per execution instance as per [Miserable Variable's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8937690/604511).

Finally, in a Tomcat deployment, I give it a HTTP interface, deploying it as per [havexz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8937575/604511).

Comment: What is your server like tomcat, jboss etc? And what is its version? As soln will differ depending upon the server.

Comment: Tomcat 6. But I want to try the method on commandline first

Comment: What exactly you mean by you have to run it first in commandline? You dont need to programmatically import jars in ur java code.

Comment: @aitchnyu Your question appears to already have a way to do it from the command line, and you even say "I am running this project as a JSP, not from a commandline" implying that you want a non-command-line solution, but then you say you "want to try the method on commandline first". Which is it?

Comment: I want the prototype app to work in commandline for testing. Then I am writing a JSP application (which I use to provide a convienient HTTP interface) that **imports** the prototype app. Sorry I was not clear with the previous comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If the jars need to be in global scope:**

Well if you want these jars to be available to all apps on the server try putting them in

```
`<tomcat_install_dir>/lib`
```

**EDIT:** @Geoffery comment: If you have access to

```
<tomcat_install_di>/conf/catalina.properties
```

then you can added your own common jars dir like:

`common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.base}/your_common_jar_folder/*.jar`

(See carefully at the end, I had added a new folder)

But either way, if the jars meant to be at global scope they should be in any of above folders. Else you have to put other common jars for logging and jdbc etc with every app.

**If the jars need to be in app scope**

And if you want these jars to be used only one specific app then put them in

```
`<your_web_app>/WEB-INF/lib`
```

Note: You can put the `<your_web_app>/WEB-INF/lib` of your development folder and if you are using the right tools then it will make these jars part of your `.war` file.

**SIDE NOTE:** Since you are running java program from command line too and having issues adding dependency jars. Sometime back [I wrote a shell script](https://github.com/paramvir-b/easy-run-java) for this purpose, hope this will help you too.

Small snippet of it:

```
Run Java easily from shell command

Usage: easyrunjava [-c <jar_name/jar_dir>,<jar_name/jar_dir>...] [-m <email_id1>,<email_id2>...] [-p <prop_file1>,<prop_file2>...] class_name [args_to_program]

Example:
`easyrunjava -p .,./dependency -m user.name@xyz.com com.example.HelloWorld`
```

Comment: You shouldn't mess with `<tomcat_install_dir>/lib`. Just put the jars from the binaries folder in `yourWarFile.war/WEB-INF/lib`. Or better yet, use [maven 3](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/web.html) or gradle to build the war for you.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet well i added more advance option but to your point the jars in the global scope have to be globally accessible else you end up deploying common jar with every app.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to put all jars in a folder in classpath? `import` is the wrong word then.

Newer versions of java allow '*' as classpath:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -server -cp 'binaries/*' ${mainClass} $*
```

should work. Note `binaries/*` is in single quotes to prevent shell expansion.