# exception while integrating mahout recommender engine in java web application

Tags: java, mahout

I am trying to implement recoemmender code in java dynamic web application using direct approach. i can compile the code but when i run the application on server i am getting following error:

**type**
Exception report

**message**
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception** 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

**root cause**
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/model/DataModel
com.demoMahout.HelperRecommender.getUserBasedRecommendation(HelperRecommender.java:96)
    com.demoMahout.HelperRecommender.doPost(HelperRecommender.java:53)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

**root cause**
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.model.DataModel
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:332)
    com.demoMahout.HelperRecommender.getUserBasedRecommendation(HelperRecommender.java:96)
    com.demoMahout.HelperRecommender.doPost(HelperRecommender.java:53)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means just what it says: you don't have the Mahout classes included in your web app! put the JAR files in `WEB-INF/lib` as you need to do with any other library a web app needs.

Comment: but why it does not take the class references from referenced library where i have added all required jars???

Comment: not sure what you are referring to. The error shows that you did not do this.

Comment: please check the answers to a question I aksed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937409/how-do-you-programatically-relative-import-a-directory-of-jar-files